# I want to open a new window/tab with POST Data, but it's not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is one of the calls that is generated via PHP:

```
                    <script>
                      var copyrecipient = [];
                      var customhintcopy = [];
                      copyrecipient.push('customer');
                      copyrecipient.push('healthinsurance');
                      customhintcopy.push('4');
                      customhintcopy.push('6');
                      $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "./content/pdf-view-bill.php",
                      data: {
                         bills: '6',
                         copyrecipient:copyrecipient,
                         customhintcopy:customhintcopy,
                         additionaltextcopy: '',
                         copycoveringnotes: '5',
                         documentationcopy: '1',
                         original: '1'
                      }
                      success: function(data){
                          var win = window.open();
                          win.document.write(data);
                      }
                    })</script>
```

The console throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on the "success-line", and i have no idea why.
What i want is a new window or tab to open, that gets sent the data i have defined above.
Anyone can help me? I'm pretty new to Ajax...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You missed comma on `}` of the `data` object.

```
data: {
    bills: '6',
    copyrecipient:copyrecipient,
    customhintcopy:customhintcopy,
    additionaltextcopy: '',
    copycoveringnotes: '5',
    documentationcopy: '1',
    original: '1'
}, // <-- Here
success: function(data){
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write(data);
}
```

Comment: Also there are multiple mistakes.

Comment: Omg, it was something that trivial... *facepalm*. 
Thanks a lot!
At least the windows open now, but there seem to be problems with the supplied POST data...
Next i need to fix those...

Comment: The resulting page is supposed to be a PDF file. Right now it opens like that:
%PDF-1.4 3 0 obj <> /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x��Z�n��g}E��&V�{�2=�^���E) `�E�|QL�^IN�|�~�~C��S�w�#R�X���S��{���㑒n�:�^8/�,^�j�81�Q� ެ��gZ<�$�|��T�:

...and so on. Do i have to supply the document type of the resultiung windows somewhere?